# Mouse over on line chart data active other data-set in Chart.js

Tags: dataset, chart.js

I'm creating a line chart using Chart.js. The chart has two datasets. The x-axis is date, and y-axis is the value. When I hover the first data in dataset 1, the first data in dataset 2 is also active(zoom). That isn't I expected. Is there any way to active only the hovered data. And is there any way to active all data by their y value, not by index.

I've tried edit the tooltips mode but the result is not I expected. It shows the tooltips in difference dataset with same index.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [{
                x: '2019-01-15',
                y: 100
            }, {
                x: '2019-02-03',
                y: 300
            }],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: [{
                x: '2019-01-03',
                y: 150
            }, {
                x: '2019-01-15',
                y: 200
            }, {
                x: '2019-02-06',
                y: 250
            }],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                position: 'bottom',
                time: {
                    min: "2019-1-1",
                    max: "2019-2-28",
                    unit: "month",
                    displayFormats: {
                        "month": "YYYY-MM",
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1gmrujo/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've tried edit the tooltips mode but the result is not I expected. It shows the tooltips in difference dataset with same index.

The `tooltip` configuration controls display of the tooltip *popup*, not the dataset points. Points are controlled by the [`hover` configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/). This is mentioned on the [page you linked](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html) (emphasis mine):

> When configuring interaction with the graph ***via hover or tooltips***, a number of different modes are available.

If you only want the single point you are hovering over to be highlighted, use:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'point'
  }
}
```

If you want the whole dataset highlighted when hovering any single dataset point, use:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'dataset'
  }
}
```

If you want to highlight the dataset and see all dataset values in the tooltip, use:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'dataset'
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'dataset'
  }
}
```